# ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

Angular version: 6.0.5

I am using a npm package created by me (also in angular) inside my angular application. On compilation the angular core files are being loaded from the node_modules inside my package folder

```
node_modules/myPackage/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11):
```

This error happened after upgrading to Angular 6.

Things tried so far:

> 1. Making the Angular versions for both the packages similar.
> 2. Adding the following line to tsconfig.json "paths": {   "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"] }

Comment: Hi Im facing the same issue, It would be helpful if you could share me how it worked pls?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ../node_modules and not just node_modules if baseUrl is src in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the current node modules and installing them again.

Use `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm i`

Also, make sure u have the right version of node modules if u have multiple versions then use `nvm use <version>` to solve it.

Also, make sure your local and global angular CLI version is the same.